# Is there any correct (effective) way to use CustomView (with or without androidx.compose.ui.viewinterop.AndroidView) inside LazyColumn?

Tags: android, androidx, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack

**What is the problem?**

Now I'm trying to use my custom Android view inside `LazyColumn`. In my opinion, because of recreating my custom views every time I scrolling, picture is very **laggy**. So, is there any way to make it smoother, other than implementing view with Compose?

**My code:**

```kotlin
LazyColumn {
    items(events){ event ->
        EventItem(event, callBack)
    }
}

@Composable
private fun EventItem(
    event: EventOverviewUiModel,
    callBack : (EventsAdapterEvent) -> Unit
) {
    AndroidView(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth(),
        factory = { context -> EventOverviewView(context) },
        update = { view -> view.bind(event) }
    )
}
```

Comment: This part of the code looks fine, this is exactly how you should work with it. Most probably your lags are because of other parts of code. 
Or your `EventOverviewView`  init is too heavy. Try replacing `AndroidView` with `Text` to see if it still lags.

Answer (score 1):

For anyone else that encounters the same problem:

As of today, there is no solution to this problem. The issue is known by Google and you can track the resolution of the issue [here](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/241959701).

If you need to use your `AndroidView` in the Compose world with a smooth scrolling, you have two workarounds:

- You have a limited number of items: you can use a simple `Column` with a `verticalScroll` and add your `AndroidView` inside ;
- You have too many items: you have to implement a `RecyclerView` and use it as an `AndroidView` instead of an `AndroidView` in a `LazyColumn`.

Comment: Please, use link formatting: `[link](url)`

Comment: Thanks, I edited the message according to your advice.

Answer (score 0):

This is solvable now, see ScrollingAndroidViewsDemo here:
https://android-review.googlesource.com/c/platform/frameworks/support/+/2394474

Note if your view doesn't have any of the "update on user interaction" logic you can just do:

```
    AndroidView(
        modifier =  ~ ,
        factory = ~ ,
        onReset = {}
    )
```